# Ignoring a file: gitignore does not do what I want

Tags: git, version-control

I searched internet and SO but could not get solution to this issue.
I am using git. I have the code, which has a branch B1 on computer C1. On another computer C2, I cloned this branch and locally, made one more branch B2. B2 is not pushed to central repository.

B1 and B2 are quite same, except one file FILE1. So I added that file to .gitignore and committed in B2. Now whenever I do some coding in B1, I push it in central repository. To get these changes on computer C2, I do

```
git pull origin B1
```

while I am on branch B2. But this gives error message:

```
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in FILE1
```

I wanted to ask, if there is a better way of bringing changes made in B1 to B2 (without bringing FILE1) or how can I improve my current method. Thanks for help, as I am new to git.

Comment: .gitignore is for files you don't want versioned EVER, not for removing files from version control.  Ideally though, you want to resolve the conflict between the files as something has change in B1 since you made the branch B2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the purpose of [`.gitignore`](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitignore.html):

> A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that git should ignore. Files already tracked by git are not affected.

So if your file is already being tracked by Git (which it seems to be in your case), adding it to `.gitignore` changes nothing.

When you get a merge conflict, it means that the file has changed both on your current working tree and where you're merging from (in your case, the remote repository). You **must* resolve any and all merge conflicts. There are lots of resources for how to resolve merge conflicts, the [Git User Manual](http://schacon.github.com/git/user-manual.html#resolving-a-merge) among them. You can also [specify that Git use the local or remote copy to resolve conflicts](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-merge.html#_merge_strategies):

```
git pull -Xtheirs origin B1
```

If you never meant to track the file, you can untrack it:

```
git rm --cached myfilename
```

[As Greg mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9234448/211563), if your intent is for the file to be a template configuration, name it as such, and then copy it and add the specialized version to `.gitignore`.

Answer (score 4):

The `.gitignore` files is used to ignore *untracked* files, such as compiled `*.o` files. Once a file has been committed to Git, the `.gitignore` no longer applies.

The usual way to solve your problem is to create a base "sample" file and store that in the repository (instead of the real file). For example, if you have a file called `foobar.config`, then create a `foobar.config.sample` file with suitable contents and put that in the repository. Also, remove the `foobar.config` file. Then, for each checkout where you need a configuration file, copy `foobar.config.sample` to `foobar.config` and edit as needed.

Another way might be to have your code recognise a "local" configuration file. So you could put the common parts of `foobar.config` into the repository, and your code also looks for a `foobar.config.local` file and overrides any settings in the main `foobar.config` file with the local settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you have checked in your foo.txt file by accident and can re-create it by other means (like via compilation of some sources), you could `git rm /path/to/foo.txt` to remove it from version control and then `.gitignore` will also do what you want.